# Algorithm not found by PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, standalone

I have troubles using PyQgis processing module with QGIS 3.8. For example, I can reproject a layer with QGIS graphic interface, but when using PyQgis processing module through the following script :

```py
    import sys
    from qgis.core import *

    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
    qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
    qgs.initQgis()
    print(QgsApplication.showSettings())

    ##Processing initialization
    sys.path.extend(['/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing', 
                     '/usr/share/qgis/python', '/usr/lib/qgis/plugins'])  # Folder for Processing
    import processing
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
    Processing.initialize()  # needed to be able to use the functions afterwards

    ##Get and load the project instance
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2154))

    ## Chargement d'une couche
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('/my/place/to/save/zone_etude.shp','zone_etude','ogr')
    project.addMapLayer(vlayer)

    param = {'INPUT':'/my/place/to/save/zone_etude.shp',
             'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
             'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
    processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", param)

    project.write('/my/place/to/save/tutoproject.qgs')
    qgs.exitQgis()
```

This code returns  :

```
Application state:
QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var:       
Prefix:     /usr
Plugin Path:        /usr/lib/qgis/plugins
Package Data Path:  /usr/share/qgis
Active Theme Name:  
Active Theme Path:  /usr/share/qgis/resources/themes//icons/
Default Theme Path: :/images/themes/default/
SVG Search Paths:   /usr/share/qgis/svg/
        /home/edelb/.local/share/profiles/default/svg/
User DB Path:   /usr/share/qgis/resources/qgis.db
Auth DB Path:   /home/edelb/.local/share/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db

Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py:112: DeprecationWarning:
gdal.py was placed in a namespace, it is now available as osgeo.gdal

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my/place/to/save/repro_bug.py", line 26, in <module>
    processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", param)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 125, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm native:reprojectlayer not found
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, using Qgis 3.8, and I don't know how I can access several of these processing algorithms like "native:reprojectlayer" or "native:saveselectedfeatures"...
Still, some processing algorithms are reachable, as this command shows:

```py
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    print("{}:{} --> {}".format(alg.provider().name(), alg.name(), alg.displayName()))
```

```
GDAL:aspect --> Aspect
GDAL:assignprojection --> Assign projection  
...  
GRASS:r.spreadpath --> r.spreadpath  
...
QGIS:vectorlayerscatterplot --> Vector layer scatterplot
QGIS:voronoipolygons --> Voronoi polygons
QGIS:zonalstatistics --> Zonal statistics
```

And for example `processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:voronoipolygons")` returns what it is supposed to return.

Comment: you need add this line `QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())` after `Processing.initialize()` for use native algorithms

Comment: I add my comment as an answer then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use **native algorithms** in a **standalone** application, you need to add the provider using:

```
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
```

It would be like this:

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
```